# Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512m

Tags: java, maven, jvm

I have tried with all possible heap sizes for JVM, but I keep getting the below exception.

```
Admin pc@Admin-PC MINGW64 /c/controller/opendaylight (master)
$  /c/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn clean install
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512m
```

Note - Don't mark this as duplicate, because I have tried with all solutions here but unable to find a final fix for this.

EDIT NOTES- Adding debug information

```
$ bash -x /c/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn clean install
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -f /etc/mavenrc ']'
+ '[' -f '/c/Users/Admin pc/.mavenrc' ']'
+ cygwin=false
+ darwin=false
+ mingw=false
+ case "`uname`" in
++ uname
+ mingw=true
+ '[' -z 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80' ']'
+ '[' -z 'C:\apache-maven-3.3.9' ']'
+ false
+ true
+ '[' -n 'C:\apache-maven-3.3.9' ']'
++ cd 'C:\apache-maven-3.3.9'
++ pwd
+ M2_HOME=/c/apache-maven-3.3.9
+ '[' -n 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80' ']'
++ cd 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80'
++ pwd
+ JAVA_HOME='/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80'
+ '[' -z '/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80' ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -n '/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80' ']'
+ '[' -x '/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/sh/java' ']'
+ JAVACMD='/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java'
+ '[' '!' -x '/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java' ']'
+ '[' -z '/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80' ']'
+ CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
+ false
++ find_maven_basedir
++ local basedir
++ local wdir
+++ pwd
++ basedir=/c/controller/opendaylight
+++ pwd
++ wdir=/c/controller/opendaylight
++ '[' /c/controller/opendaylight '!=' / ']'
++ '[' -d /c/controller/opendaylight/.mvn ']'
+++ cd /c/controller/opendaylight/..
+++ pwd
++ wdir=/c/controller
++ '[' /c/controller '!=' / ']'
++ '[' -d /c/controller/.mvn ']'
++ basedir=/c/controller
++ break
++ echo /c/controller
+ MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=/c/controller
++ concat_lines /c/controller/.mvn/jvm.config
++ '[' -f /c/controller/.mvn/jvm.config ']'
+++ tr -s '\n' ' '
 ' echo '-Xmx512m
  -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M'
+ false
+ export MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR
+ MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=' clean install'
+ export MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS
+ exec '/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java' $'-Xmx512m\r' $'\r' -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -classpath /c/apache-maven-3.3.9/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/c/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/c/apache-maven-3.3.9 -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/c/controller org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher clean install
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512m
```

Comment: This might help you [Link](https://bukkit.org/threads/invalid-maximum-heap-size.256994/)

Comment: 1) can you please try running that shell command in a debug (`bash -x /c/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn`) and put output of that here?
2) can you please run whatever java command is there with `-version` flag? (in my case on Mac it's going to be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version`)
3) can you please try to see how much memory is available to your Cygwin (maybe by `free` or by right clicking on window title and exploring what's there, it seems you're on Windows?)

Comment: This might mean you have less than 512 MB if virtual memory free although on a 64-bit OS this would be very unusual.

Comment: It can mean the JVM tried to allocate that much space and the OS returned an error message.

Comment: @Ivan updated with debug info above

Comment: @Vishal point #3 about the available memory would help us all alot

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same issue.

Instead of twiddeling settings, make sure you installled the 64bit version (and not 32 which the website gave me by default).